# GIT LFS issue - deleted file still has reference in LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to add a remote repository and merge with one of the branches in the remote. All this works good, but the issue is when i try to push the new branch. The error message is:

```
Unable to find source for object e10ac6e7ed8d242c9303614f5ecdd4ddec4b570048354fb768863191136b9431 (try running git lfs fetch --all)
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/5), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git/sms/un/pr_2/lcd/lcd.git'
```

The issue is there was a temp document committed by mistake and was removed, but LFS still has a reference to this document : ~$vironmentSetupGuide.docx

So when i run

```
git lfs fetch --all
fetch: 29 object(s) found, done.
fetch: Fetching all references...
[e10ac6e7ed8d242c9303614f5ecdd4ddec4b570048354fb768863191136b9431] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it: [404] Object does not exist on the server or you don't have permissions to access it
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://git/sms/un/pr2/lcd/lcd.git/info/lfs'
```

I even tried to create that file in my local, but that didn't help either.
I also created the file under .git/lfs/e1/0a/123332423324. That didn't work too.
How do we resolve this. Please advise. Thanks